# Stop Phpunit execution during a TestSuite

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I use a class to execute a testsuite with PhpUnit like :

```
$suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('PHPUnit Framework');
$suite->addTestSuite('ClassOne');
$suite->addTestSuite('ClassTwo');
return $suite;
```

To start the unit test :

```
# phpunit --stop-on-failure TestSuite.php
```

If "ClassOne" has an error or exception, the test continue with "ClassTwo".
How I could stop all the testsuites if the first test failed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Works with PHPUnit 3.5.14

Using the code below the outputs are as expected:

#### Two fails running it normally:

```
phpunit AllTests.php 
PHPUnit 3.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

FF

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.25Mb

There were 2 failures:

1) Framework_AssertTest::testFails
Failed asserting that <boolean:true> matches expected <boolean:false>.

/home/edo/test/AllTests.php:7

2) Other_AssertTest::testFails
Failed asserting that <boolean:true> matches expected <boolean:false>.

/home/edo/test/AllTests.php:13

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 2.
```

#### and one fail running it with `--stop-on-failure`

```
phpunit --stop-on-failure AllTests.php 
PHPUnit 3.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) Framework_AssertTest::testFails
Failed asserting that <boolean:true> matches expected <boolean:false>.

/home/edo/test/AllTests.php:7

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

### AllTests.php

```
<?php


class Framework_AssertTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testFails() {
        $this->assertSame(false, true);
    }
}

class Other_AssertTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testFails() {
        $this->assertSame(false, true);
    }

}

class Framework_AllTests
{
    public static function suite()
    {
        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('PHPUnit Framework');

        $suite->addTestSuite('Framework_AssertTest');
        $suite->addTestSuite('Other_AssertTest');

        return $suite;
    }
}

class Other_AllTests
{
    public static function suite()
    {
        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('PHPUnit Framework');

        $suite->addTestSuite('Other_AssertTest');

        return $suite;
    }
}

class AllTests
{
    public static function suite()
    {
        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('PHPUnit');

        $suite->addTest(Framework_AllTests::suite());

        return $suite;
    }
}
```

As a side node. If you look at the [`documentation of the current version`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/index.html) only "suites by file system" and "suites by xml config" are explained options. Just to keep that in mind if you can migrate at the point.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in phpunit. Upgrade phpunit to the latest version. If that does not help, open a bug report.